# How to increase performance of merge statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, merge, query-optimization

I have to execute merge statement on SQL server DB with below requirement.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.cross_charge D
USING
    (
        SELECT
            PROJECT_CODE
            , CROSS_CHARGE_OU
        FROM
            dbo.cross_charge
        WHERE
            PROJECT_CODE = #PROJECT_CODE1
            AND CROSS_CHARGE_OU = #CROSS_CHARGE_OU1
    ) S
ON (
       D.PROJECT_CODE = S.PROJECT_CODE
       AND D.CROSS_CHARGE_OU = S.CROSS_CHARGE_OU
   )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
                      D.PROJECT_CODE = #PROJECT_CODE3
                      , D.CROSS_CHARGE_OU = #CROSS_CHARGE_OU3
                      , D.CROSS_CHARGE_START = #CROSS_CHARGE_START1
                      , D.CROSS_CHARGE_END = #CROSS_CHARGE_END1
                      , D.IS_Enable = #IS_Enable1
                      , D.UpdatedDate = #UpdatedDate1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
                          (
                              PROJECT_CODE
                              , CROSS_CHARGE_OU
                              , CROSS_CHARGE_START
                              , CROSS_CHARGE_END
                              , IS_Enable
                              , UpdatedDate
                          )
                      VALUES
                          (
                              #PROJECT_CODE2, #CROSS_CHARGE_OU2, #CROSS_CHARGE_START, #CROSS_CHARGE_END, #IS_Enable, #UpdatedDate
                          )
```

I have to pass Project_code and cross_charge_ou as input parameter and based on select result it will either insert or update the record.

When I am executing this query for 100 records then It is taking 35 seconds which is too much as I have to execute this statement for 50K+ records.

Do we have any options to improve the performance of this query as I am not much aware of SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess you should be using a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in your `USING` rather than querying the same table that you're merging into. No clue if that would improve performance though.

Comment: paste the execution plan as well , also what are indexes on those tables, also what do you mean by # ?

Comment: Posting the actual execution plan will help, but frankly, I've had performance issues with MERGE and always went back to dedicated INSERT/UPDATE statements within a transaction.

Comment: @eshirvana - # stand as input parameter which will accept input.. Also SQL server DB is handled by separate team and I have no clue about it.. Could you please tell me more about execute plan as I did not understand ?

Comment: @KushalKaria here is how to [display execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15)